# Display data from SQL Lite in Android app using phone gap

Tags: javascript, android, html, eclipse, cordova

I  am using Phonegap in Eclipse to make an android app. So I've made an excel file, then I converted it to a db file through using sql lite. Now i have to access that database in javascript. Can anyone give me an idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you can access a database that you created through the application Phonegap itself.

You can check the online doc (the link I provide is for Cordova version 1.5.0 but it should be similar for other versions) for more information:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLResultSet

The problem is that you want to access a database that you pre-propulated. So, the main question about this issue would be: where to put my database file?

I suggest that you read the following links which should answer your questions:

- [Reading a local sqlite file from phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424650/reading-a-local-sqlite-file-from-phonegap)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/XlenKNxmoqE

I hope this information will help you.